# How to get the multiple value from XML by Python?

Tags: python, xml

```
I have this XML file for example:
```

```
    <ROOT>
        <name> SOME_NAME </name>
            <ValueFilter>
            <Value ID='bla'/>
            <Value ID='bla2'/>
            <Value ID='bla3'/>
            </ValueFilter>  
        <MetaData>
            <MultiValue attrid="attr1">
                <Value> Attrubite1 and some text </Value>
            </MultiValue>
        </MetaData>
        <name> SOME_NAME_2 </name>
            <ValueFilter>
            <Value ID='bla'/>
            <Value ID='bla2'/>
            <Value ID='bla3'/>
            </ValueFilter>  
        <MetaData>
            <MultiValue attrid="attr2">
                <Value> Attrubite2 and some text </Value>
            </MultiValue>
        </MetaData>
        <name> SOME_NAME_3 </name>
            <ValueFilter>
            <Value ID='bla'/>
            <Value ID='bla2'/>
            <Value ID='bla3'/>
            </ValueFilter>  
        <MetaData>
            <MultiValue attrid="attr3">
                <Value> Attrubite3 and some text </Value>
            </MultiValue>
        </MetaData> 
    </ROOT>
```

What I need is get out from this xml (I mean delete) the followig rows:

```
    <MultiValue attrid="attr1">
        <Value> Attrubite1 and some text </Value>
    </MultiValue>
```

the same for attribute 2 and 3.

I cannot think up how to do this
I tried do this by xml.etree.ElementTree and simple Python lib xml and get nothing or it is not work

The main reason is how to get correct sub tag? And how actually do this?

Answer (score 1):

Recommend you a simple library.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils
# xml = utils.getFileContent('your xml path')
xml = '''
<ROOT>
    <name> SOME_NAME </name>
        <ValueFilter>
        <Value ID='bla'/>
        <Value ID='bla2'/>
        <Value ID='bla3'/>
        </ValueFilter>  
    <MetaData>
        <MultiValue attrid="attr1">
            <Value> Attrubite1 and some text </Value>
        </MultiValue>
    </MetaData>
    <name> SOME_NAME_2 </name>
        <ValueFilter>
        <Value ID='bla'/>
        <Value ID='bla2'/>
        <Value ID='bla3'/>
        </ValueFilter>  
    <MetaData>
        <MultiValue attrid="attr2">
            <Value> Attrubite2 and some text </Value>
        </MultiValue>
    </MetaData>
    <name> SOME_NAME_3 </name>
        <ValueFilter>
        <Value ID='bla'/>
        <Value ID='bla2'/>
        <Value ID='bla3'/>
        </ValueFilter>  
    <MetaData>
        <MultiValue attrid="attr3">
            <Value> Attrubite3 and some text </Value>
        </MultiValue>
    </MetaData> 
</ROOT>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)  # create doc
MetaDatas = doc.selects('MetaData')

for d in MetaDatas:
    d.remove()

print(doc.html)
# utils.saveFile('test.xml', doc.html)
```

Result:

```
<ROOT>
    <name> SOME_NAME </name>
        <ValueFilter>
        <Value ID='bla' />
        <Value ID='bla2' />
        <Value ID='bla3' />
        </ValueFilter>  
    <name> SOME_NAME_2 </name>
        <ValueFilter>
        <Value ID='bla' />
        <Value ID='bla2' />
        <Value ID='bla3' />
        </ValueFilter>  
    <name> SOME_NAME_3 </name>
        <ValueFilter>
        <Value ID='bla' />
        <Value ID='bla2' />
        <Value ID='bla3' />
        </ValueFilter>   
</ROOT>
```

[Here](https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples) are more examples. This lib is easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really the way to ask questions around here (and, incidentally, your xml is invalid -  several tags aren't closed), but for future reference - using the lxml libraray makes it a fairly simple task:

```
from lxml import etree
some_xml = """ [your xml above, fixed] """
doc = etree.XML(some_xml)
for elem in doc.xpath("//Value[contains(.,'Attrubite')]"):
    doc.remove(elem.getparent().getparent())
print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
```

Output:

```
<ROOT>
        <name> SOME_NAME </name>
            <ValueFilter>
            <Value ID="bla"/>
            <Value ID="bla2"/>
            <Value ID="bla3"/>
            </ValueFilter>  
        <name> SOME_NAME_2 </name>
            <ValueFilter>
            <Value ID="bla"/>
            <Value ID="bla2"/>
            <Value ID="bla3"/>
            </ValueFilter>  
        <name> SOME_NAME_3 </name>
            <ValueFilter>
            <Value ID="bla"/>
            <Value ID="bla2"/>
            <Value ID="bla3"/>
            </ValueFilter>  
        </ROOT>
```